# Is there a command key for entering ZenMode on Github?

Tags: github, editor

GitHub now allows people [to switch to a mostly-blank screen](https://github.com/blog/1379-zen-writing-mode) when writing docs.

Is there a command key to rapidly enter this mode without having to click around and distract myself further?

Comment: Having read the FAQ once again, I cannot determine what is off-topic about the question of an editor / tool.  S.O. is rife with questions on git, and a `github` tag exists!  As well the question had a specific answer, which was given.  Is another site preferable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. `<CTRL>-<SHIFT>-<L>` will enter the zone.